# Python: How to apply list comprehension to make list of lambdas?

Tags: python, lambda, list-comprehension

This code prints `2 2 2` instead of `1 2 3`. I'd understand this result if `k` being referred to is shared between each list items, but I couldn't be certain about it.

```
flist = [(lambda x: k) for k in range(3)]
print(flist[0](0), flist[1](0), flist[2](0))
print(k)  # Fails as expected
```

1. How does list comprehension work exactly? On what namespace does `k` exist?
2. How should I change the code to get `1 2 3` with about the same code complexities/length as list comprehension? I'm hardcoding list of flists, and I don't want my code to be excessively long.

Comment: flist = [(lambda x, y=k: y) for k in range(3)]

Answer (score 0):

this is simple it should be like this:

```
>>> flist = [ k+1 for k in range(3)]
>>> flist
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: I'm making array of functions, not its individual results.

Comment: can you show the expected output what you want

Comment: [lambda x:0, lambda x:1, lambda x:2]
Silly mistakes;

Comment: lambda is inbuilt function, it will be stored as function not string